# How to split the same string depending on its characters?

Tags: c#, arrays, string, linq, split

I want to be able to create an array of characters as strings, from a given string.
Characters between **()** should be 1 element, and each character outside the **()** should be counted likewise. So a string like:

```
string test = "(af)sd(abc)abc"
```

would generate an array that look like this:

```
string[] testSplitted = { "af", "s", "d", "abc", "a", "b", "c" };
```

The code below is only able to make the characters inside the **()** items of the array but not the characters outside the **()**. So instead I get:

```
string[] testSplitted = { "af", "sd", "abc", "abc" };
```

```
 public static string[] transmissions = { "(ab)(bc)(ca)", "abc", "(abc)(abc)(abc)", "(zyx)bc" };
 public static string[] words = { "abc", "bca", "dac", "dbc", "cba" };

 public static void Main()
        {
            for (int y = 0; y < N; y++)
            {
                string[] charSplit = transmissions[y].Replace("(", "").Replace(")", "").Split();
                int K = 0;
                foreach (var item in words)
                {
                    int matches = 0;
                    for (int i = 0; i < item.Length; i++)
                    {
                        if (!charSplit[i].Contains(item[i])) { break; }
                        matches++;
                    }
                    if (matches == 3) { K++; }
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Case #" + (y + 1) + ": " + K);
            }
        }
```

Is there anyway I can split the characters outside of the **()** to separate elements aswell?

Comment: Build a simple state machine. Walk the characters in the string. If you find a character outside of `()`, add it to a `List<string>`. When you encounter a `(`, add the characters to a clear `StringBuilder`. When you hit `)`, add the contents of the buffer to the list. Easy to read, and **O(n)**

Answer (score 1):

Here's a pretty simple state machine that's **O(n)**.

```
public static IEnumerable<string> StringWalker(string input)
{
    bool inParens = false;
    StringBuilder buffer = new StringBuilder();
    List<string> result = new List<string>();

    foreach (var c in input)
    {
        if (c == '(')
        {
            if (inParens)
            {
                throw new Exception("Nested Parens not allowed");
            }
            inParens = true;
            buffer.Clear();
        }
        else if (inParens)
        {
            if (c == ')')
            {
                inParens = false;
                result.Add(buffer.ToString());
            }
            else
            {
                buffer.Append(c);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            result.Add(c.ToString());
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

The results look like:

```
abc(de)(fgh)ijk:  ==>  (a) (b) (c) (de) (fgh) (i) (j) (k) 
(abc)de(f)gh(ijklm)nop:  ==>  (abc) (d) (e) (f) (g) (h) (ijklm) (n) (o) (p)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using *reguar expressions* and `Match` all the items:

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

...

string test = "(af)sd(abc)abc";

string[] testSplitted = Regex
  .Matches(test, @"\(.*?\)|.")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value.Trim('(', ')'))
  .ToArray();
```

**Pattern explained:**

```
  \(.*?\) - zero or more characters (aw few as possible) within (...)
  |       - OR
  .       - single character
```

**More tests:**

```
string[] tests = new string[] {
  "(ab)(bc)(ca)", 
  "abc", 
  "(abc)(abc)(abc)", "(zyx)bc" 
};

static string[] Perform(string value) => Regex
  .Matches(value, @"\(.*?\)|.")
  .Cast<Match>()
  .Select(match => match.Value.Trim('(', ')'))
  .ToArray();

string report = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, tests
  .Select(test => $"{test,15} => {string.Join(", ", Perform(test))}"));

Console.Write(report);
```

**Output:**

```
   (ab)(bc)(ca) => ab, bc, ca
            abc => a, b, c
(abc)(abc)(abc) => abc, abc, abc
        (zyx)bc => zyx, b, c
```

Please, [fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/MBJ5Zv) yourself